# Find the dimension of the vector space $U$ of all linear transformations of $V$ to $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have started learning about linear transformations after finishing with vector spaces and I stumbled upon this problem in the question.

I have the following:  $V-R^2$, $W-R^3$

I honestly couldn't find a way to approach such a problem, I hope someone can help.

Comment: Key word: linear transformations thought as matrices thought as vectors.

Comment: Well a transformation from $R^2$ to $R^3$ requires a $3 x 2$ matrix

Comment: so I am guessing the answer here would be 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal L (V, W)$ denote the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$. Then 
$$\dim \mathcal L(V, W) = (\dim V)(\dim W).$$

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: No problem :) And yeh, you're right that a linear map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$ requires a $3 \times 2$ matrix, so the answer is 6.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the vector space you are referring to, is denoted by, L(V,W). The set of all linear transformations between two vector spaces, over the SAME field, is a vector space. Here they are both finite dimensional.

I am not taking R2 and R3, instead, I'm going to give you an idea, for generalization.

Suppose V is of dimension 'n'  and W is of dimension 'm', can you like give a shot at how many elements, the basis of L(V,W) would have?